# what does **for want of commitment** mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does **for want of commitment** mean in the following sentence? (emphasis added)

> If the reports have not been successful, it is not ***for want of commitment*** by the Bank.

[Yusuf, Shahid. 2009. Development Economics through the Decades : A Critical Look at 30 Years of the World Development Report. Washington, DC: World Bank. p 107.](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2586/47108.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: In this context, ***for*** means ***because of, caused by***. And ***want*** means ***lack, absence of***. So whatever the reason the reports weren't successful, it wasn't because the Bank wasn't sufficiently committed (the context as given doesn't specify exactly *what* the Bank was by implication "adequately" committed to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unfamiliar, right? It's true that, to many learners, *want* is always a verb (meaning something like "need" or "desire)", but in this sentence, *want* is a noun.

Let's get to the point, *for want of something* means:

> **[for want of something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/for-want-of-something)**
>   　　because someone lacks something
>   　　*She could not make the trip for want of money.*

If you look it up in [another dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/want) (the Oxford dictionary, definition 1, NOUN), you'll find this:

> **[want](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/want)** [mass noun] A lack or deficiency of something:
>   'Victorian houses which are in want of repair'
>   'for want of a better location we ate our picnic in the cemetery'

To sum it up, it's as FumbleFingers wrote in his comment, *it is not for want of commitment by the Bank* means "it is not because the Bank lacks commitment".